# Devise redirect after login fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise

All the questions I've found are related to a successful login with the helper
`after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`

I have a login form in the index of the site, and when the login fails it redirects to **"users/sign_in"**

But how can I redirect to my `site#index` when the login fails?

Answer (score 102):

1. Create a ***custom_failure.rb*** in your ***lib*** directory, with:

   ```
    class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
      def redirect_url
        your_path
      end

      def respond
        if http_auth?
          http_auth
        else
          redirect
        end
      end
    end
   ```
2. In your Devise initializer, include:

   ```
      config.warden do |manager|
        manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
      end
   ```
3. Make sure Rails is loading your lib files, in your ***application.rb*** :

   ```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
   ```

Don't forget to restart your server.

I don't think there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: This didn't work. I know it's the stock answer from the devise wiki.

Comment: The contents of the `respond` method can be refactored to `http_auth? ? http_auth : redirect`. Works great!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it still redirects back to the login

Comment: This worked for me using Devise 3.2.4. Make sure when you include or change any of these files that you restart the server. You'll probably get an error like this: `NameError - undefined local variable or method 'login' for #<CustomFailure:0x007ffc4aeb9328>`if you don't.

Comment: It works for my but only for a session. How would I go about for a registration?

Comment: Works great in Rails 5 with Devise 4.3.0. Just put the file custom_failure.rb in /app/models/concerns and skip the autoload_paths step #3. Thanks @Marcao, you saved my time!

Answer (score 15):

If you use your own `SessionsController`, you can re-assign the `:recall` value of `auth_options` to recall the `controller#method` you want before running `warden.authenticate!(auth_options)`, for example:

in app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  #...
  def create
    #...
    auth_options = { :recall => 'site#index', :scope => :user }
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    #...
  end
  #...
end
```

With this way, you don't need to create the customized FailureApp and modify the configs.

Comment: This modifies the url to be the users/sign_in

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens with devise 3.1.0

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in"
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create
Completed 401 Unauthorized
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new
```

new gets called because of the auth_options defined at the end of gems/devise-3.1.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

You should redefine the auth_options used in the create action. I copied the controller in app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb of my Rails application and replaced the auth_options method like this

```
def auth_options
  { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "Home#new" }
end
```

It does the trick, but the url is still /users/sign_in

I'll try to fix that as well.

Comment: I'm on devise 3.2.2 now. The solution of Marcao works perfectly. No need to copy and patch devise controllers or set auth_options.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default sign_in path.

Check out [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: Thanks @MikeH, I tried this.

**devise_for :users do
 get 'users', :to => 'site#index', :as => :user_root # Rails 3
end**

Works perfect redirecting to my index for all cases, except when a login fails. In this case it redirect to user/sign_in, and I want to be redirected to "site#index".

Comment: Hmm.  When the login fails, devise's failure app redirects to **new_#{scope}_session_path** (new_user_session_path in your case).  When you do **rake routes**, what controller/action is shown for this resource path?

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I am still looking for it…

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Marcao's answer, I highly recommend placing some [debugger](https://github.com/pry/pry) in your CustomFailure respond method in order to better understand what is going on.

```
Class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    binding.pry
    super
  end
end
```

If you look at the [FailureApp Devise Source Code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/dd5de829c944dd955e4b35074c60798c3ad4b947/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L35) for the respond method it is super easy to understand what is going on.

```
def respond
  if http_auth?
    http_auth
  elsif warden_options[:recall]
    recall
  else
    redirect
  end
end
```

So for example in order to return a redirect_url you would want to make sure that your `respond` code conditionals eventually return `redirect`.

However if you want to maybe return a standard 401 status as defined in the [http_auth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/dd5de829c944dd955e4b35074c60798c3ad4b947/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L45) method, you want to verify that your `respond` method code returns `http_auth`.

Thus it is worth your while to look into the definition of the `http_auth?`
In particular, note the: `request.xhr?` method, which will return 0 for json requests (recall that 0 actually evaluates to true in ruby)

```
def http_auth?
  if request.xhr?
    Devise.http_authenticatable_on_xhr
  else
    !(request_format && is_navigational_format?)
  end
end
```

And maybe check your initializers/devise file for `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr` or `config.navigational_formats` in order to control the response that you want. This configuration can really affect what Devise returns and can often lead to unexpected behavior due to what it does here under the hood.