# Handling Devise login in my own controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'd like to override the way Devise currently handle the login flow. I don't need/want /users/sign_in, I just want to use my own root_path for login handling, i.e. logging user in and handling failed password entries.

I have successfully created the form which logs in, but if an user fails to put his/her password correctly, he/she being redirected to /users/sign_in. How to make sure I keep on the same action and handle failed passwords?

Comment: probably this is the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: Not quite. It just changes the route name, but if I get a failed password check, I'll end up in devise view, not mine.

Comment: You can use materialize devise views by running `rails generate devise:views` and customize the hell out of them.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to customize the view. I want to use my own controller for signing in. I want to _replace_ sessions controller on devise.

Comment: Product owner requirement. Yes, I know, but it's still a requirement.