# Devise redirect after users fail signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise, overriding

**I know there is a wiki page about it**, but since I'm very new to Rails I am having lot of difficulties in understanding that page.

I had to override registration controller for my user. When user fails to signin I want him to be redirected to my custom signin page. But the application send him to the signin page inside the gem.

How can I accomplish that? **Where should I put this class and how can I change it?**
I have multiple models, each of them has a different signin page. **How can I set the scope for each model?**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def redirect_url

    #return super unless [:worker, :employer, :user].include?(scope) #make it specific to a scope
    new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
  end

 # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
 def respond
   if http_auth?
     http_auth
   else
     redirect
   end
 end
```

end

Devise is a powerful gem but some wiki pages don't consider that there can be lots of new programmers

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Take a look at this [post][1].

It may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail

Comment: Ok this is what I tried:
I've already set in routes for each of my model the new_"model"_session_path as the wiki suggests but I have the same problem of the question up here. Fails signin do not redirect to my views but to devise ones

Comment: where did you place your CustomFailure.rb file? Does it still look the same as you posted above?

Comment: @ply the problem is this. I don't know how to put that class. Should I create a new file for each of model and where should I put that file? 
Or do I have to keep just one file for all of models?

Comment: Don't forget to restart the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my auth failure over-ride class in `/lib` directly.

Here's a bare-bones version that shows how to handle different scopes for users.

```
class MyAuthFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  # add different cases here for diff scopes.
  def redirect_url 
    if warden_options[:scope] == :user 
      root_path 
    elsif warden_options[:scope] == :admin 
      admin_root_path 
    end 
  end 

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end  
end
```

You'd put this class in `/lib/my_auth_failure.rb`

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work for me. I did like you said.I need to register admin too.

   `elsif warden_options[:scope] == :admin 
      new_admin_session_path
   end`

And from my routes:
`new_admin_session GET /admin(.:format) admin/sessions#new` but it keeps redirecting to /signin instead of /admin

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great, but the you'll run into problems testing if you don't do what is suggested in this article:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Your tests will still redirect using the default.

for example:

```
current_path.should == signin_path
```

would fail because the current path would actually be `users/sign_in` or something.