# How to make devise redirects to facebook login when user is not authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Rails application that uses devise and omniauth for authentication. Only facebook users are permitted. Facebook login working well, omniauth call backs working well.

My Gemfile include the basic, among other:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

In my "books" view controller, i've added devise authentication:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

The problem: when user authenticate_user! fails, devise is redirecting to a sign_in page (where user type username, e-mail, password, confirmation). I do not want this behavior as I only want facebook users. I need devise to redirect to facebook login if authenticate_user fails.

How to make devise redirects to facebook login when user is not authenticated?

Comment: Please look at this almost same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way will be to use a `custom devise failure app` and override the `redirect` function.

Something like below will work :

1. Create a initializer, something like `custom_failure_app.rb`.
2. Create a class `CustomFailureApp` which will inherit the `Devise::FailureApp`
3. Override the `redirect` function.

   ```
   class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp

     # will be called wen some failure occurs. 
     # Like unauthorized, session_expiry etc
     def redirect 
       message = warden.message || warden_options[:message]
       if message == :timeout
           # session expires
       else
           # unauthorized
           # redirect_to "facebook.com"
       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. Add another initializer, something like `devise.rb` and put the following code in it.

   ```
   Devise.setup do |config|
     config.warden do |manager|
       manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks - it worked. I've also had to add the initializer code

    config.warden do |manager|
      manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
    end

and the lib directory scanning

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Comment: I can't get this to work, I still get redirected to the login page

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
match '/auth/failure', :to => 'your_controller#failure'
```

to your `routes.rb` and then redirecting from within the failure method inside your controller.

Comment: Thanks - but it not working as expected. When authenticate_user! fails (because user is not logged in yet), it is redirected to /users/sign_in and /auth/failure route is not called

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates gives great screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication how to use "omniauth-facebook" gem. And you can use this fix to sign in with standart Devise methods: [Sign in to Devise using omniauth-facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941850/sign-in-to-devise-using-omniauth-facebook)