# Rails devise if session sign_in error, then redirect to some page (back)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

How can i change standart devise session_controller, so that if, for example i entered incorrect password i'm redirected :back (is not required), and see my error's...

For what i need this? Becouse i have my login only in template which is rendered in layout left block on all pages, and i didn't have new action-view...

*So how to do error's redirect to other page with validation message errors... ?*

Here is standart session_controller (now i didn't create it one, it is "nested"):

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end
  end

  protected

  def serialize_options(resource)
    methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
    methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
    methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
  end

  def auth_options
    { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new" }
  end
end
```

also method in appcontroller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)      
    case resource
      when User then 
        user = User.find(current_user.id)
        total_markup_for_user = user.groups.map(&:markup).sum
        if current_cart.present?
          cart_id = current_cart.id
        else
          cart_id = nil
        end
        ***
        end
        if request.referrer.to_s.include? "users"
          root_path
        else
          request.referrer 
        end
      when Admin::Admin then :admin_mainpage
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise has documentation that shows you how to override their default redirects here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Basically you would go into your application_controller.rb and for example write something like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || new_survey_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 root_path
end
```

end

hope it helps

Comment: i have some login in this method's and with this i could get troubles

Comment: but how to do with UNsuccessfull sign in ?

Comment: you have to create a method and have it load it in your devise initalizer. take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail

Comment: i tried this, but get uninitialized constant CustomFailure error, even if i add config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: i name'd it CustomFailure.rb also try custom_failure_controller.rb, and put it in lib folder.... but nothing

Comment: but let's forget for a while about redirecting.... it's not so requring... how to display sign_in errors, need to put some code in layout?

Comment: Default...  now i didnt see them

Comment: devise_error_messages!  - nothing (note that i use partial and display it not in partial...)... but in registration area all is ok

Comment: with <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  <%- end -%>      i get only devise.failure.user.invalid message

Comment: i get only devise.failure.user.invalid message for bad password, but must get something like password incorect... also get not_found_in_database

Comment: hey did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, add a new respond_with in case sign_in returns false.

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  if sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  else
    respond_with resource, location: root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: also i still (if enter wrong password) get route to **/users/sign_in

Comment: i think that for some reasons it didn't go there.... becouse i didn't ever get flash[:notice] = "lololol" in else case... but in if all is ok

Comment: could yo give full code with routes and full session controller?

Comment: where have you been lost( ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I suggest looking through the docs iRichLau provided.