# Rails Devise/Token authentication: redirect if token wrong or missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, token

I've implemented Devise with token authentication/json api. 
My problem now, whenever the "?auth_token" is wrong or missing, devise redirects me "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily" to my intended json error response instead of giving it back directly: "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden".

My error response comes from my SessionsController < Devise::SessionsControllers "new" action, which I assume is probably the wrong place for it.

I can't find the place where devise does the redirect or where I can change this behavior. Can anyone maybe give me a clue?

Thank you very much,
chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a **custom failure** ruby file and provide the redirects as you want  by putting it in your lib directory and then include it in your devise `initializer` like it's mentioned in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail?rq=1).

Definition of failure application is defined in:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb

OR

You can use the following code in your own controller:

```
before_filter :correct_auth, :if => { request.format == :json }

  def correct_auth
    unless current_user
      render :json => {'error' => 'authentication error'}, :status => 403
    end
  end
```

So if your `auth_token` is incorrect that means that no user should log in to the application and so you can display `authentication error 403`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I just tried your second approach, but I still get the redirect as response. If I follow the redirect I'm lead to the correct message. However I want to get rid of this redirect.

I will try your first approach. I remember that I already tried to create a custom failure and also got into some troubles.

Comment: The first approach worked! Thanks. 

I found out now, that my http client, over which I sent my requests, shows a "(( Zero-length response returned from server. ))" instead of a 401 unauthorized... so I assumed something was wrong with my implementation

Answer (score 3):

Just for documentation purposes, here the steps I performed:

[HOWTO devise custom failure app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)

Add to **devise.rb**

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

Create **lib/devise/custom_failure.rb**

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def redirect_url
    login_page_url
  end

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      if request.format.json?
        self.status = :unauthorized
        self.response_body = { :elements => {:id => "Authentication Failed", :description =>   "Invalid or missing authentication token"} }.to_json
        self.content_type = "json"
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thanks for the solution