# Rails 5 Devise: Return JSON On sign_in Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Everything I seem to find on this issue is out of date and/or doesn't work.

GOAL: When a user tries to sign in via JSON from a mobile application and the username or password is wrong, I would like Rails to return JSON data so the errors can be displayed on the app.

So far I have done the following:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do |format|
      format.json {render :json => resource } # this code will get executed for json request
    end
  end
end
```

This works well on success, but I'm not sure what to do when it fails. Right now it returns an undefined method error:

```
undefined method `users_url' for #<Users::SessionsController:0x0000000195fa28>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. CustomFailure never seemed to work, no matter how many things I tried. I was able to do this within the SessionsController via handle_failed_login:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
  after_filter :handle_failed_login, :only => :new
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do |format|
      format.json {render :json => resource } # this code will get executed for json request
    end
  end

  private
  def handle_failed_login
    if failed_login?
      render json: { success: false, errors: ["Login Credentials Failed"] }, status: 401
    end
  end 

  def failed_login?
    (options = env["warden.options"]) && options[:action] == "unauthenticated"
  end 
end
```

Comment: `after_filter :handle_failed_login, :only => :new` => `after_action :handle_failed_login, :only => :create`

Comment: This didn't work for me on Rails 5.1.2. The callback never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail) that will point you in the right direction.

Basically you need to handle the login failure. You could do this:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    elsif request.content_type == "application/json"
      self.status = 401
      self.content_type = "application/json"
      self.response_body = {success: false, error: "Unauthorized"}.to_json
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

This handles JSON requests. I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I could never get CustomFailure to work. I got it working with handle_failed_login

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem following the guide at [the devise JWT github](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/wiki/Configuring-devise-for-APIs). I could not get the custom `FailureApp` to take over and respond.

After some debugging, the failure app was registered but the key line inside of `http_auth_body` was `return super unless request_format == :json`.

I needed to add `defaults: { format: :json }` to my devise routes configuration in order for the request format to be JSON and not HTML. Once this was resolved, the custom failure app took over and responded correctly with JSON.

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json } #FIX
end

# devise/failure_app.rb
class FailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def http_auth_body
    return super unless request_format == :json

    {
      sucess: false,
      message: i18n_message
    }.to_json
  end
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = FailureApp
  end
end
```